# Why is Set<? extends Foo<?>> allowed, but Set<Foo<?>> is not

Tags: java, generics

I want to know how generics work in this kind of situation and why
`Set<? extends Foo<?>> set3 = set1;` is allowed but `Set<Foo<?>> set2 = set1;` is not?

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestGenerics {
    public static <T> void test() {
        Set<T> set1 = new HashSet<>();
        Set<?> set2 = set1;             // OK
    }

    public static <T> void test2() {
        Set<Foo<T>> set1 = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Foo<?>> set2 = set1;           // COMPILATION ERROR
        Set<? extends Foo<?>> set3 = set1; // OK
    }
}

class Foo<T> {}
```

Comment: An interesting reading about this "issue": https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/7709086

Comment: @Lino: This question is similar to and related to "*What is PECS*", but not exactly the same. This question is about PECS, but specifically applied to the case when the type arguments themselves are types which have type parameters. That makes this a particularly tricky special case, which warrants its own question. (But I'd be surprised if there is no other exactly duplicate question some where.)

Answer (score 9):

Simply said, this is because `Set<? extends Foo<?>>` is covariant (with the `extends` keyword). Covariant types are read-only and the compiler will refuse any write action, like `Set.add(..)`.

`Set<Foo<?>>` is not covariant. It does not block write or read actions.

This...

```
Set<Foo<String>> set1 = new HashSet<>();
Set<Foo<?>> set2 = set1; // KO by compiler
```

... is illegal because otherwise I could for example put a `Foo<Integer>` into `set1` via `set2`.

```
set2.add(new Foo<Integer>()); // Whoopsie
```

But...

```
Set<Foo<String>> set1 = new HashSet<>();
Set<? extends Foo<?>> set3 = set1; // OK
```

... is covariant (`extends` keyword), so it is legal. For example, the compiler will refuse a write operation like `set3.add(new Foo<Integer>())`, but accept a read operation like `set3.iterator()`.

```
Iterator<Foo<String>> fooIterator = set3.iterator(); // OK
set3.add(new Foo<String>()); // KO by compiler
```

See these posts for a better explanation:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/7709086
- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-java-generic-types-covariance-and-contravariance-88f4c19763d2

Comment: Did you mean `Foo<Integer> foo; set2.add(foo);` because `set2.add(42)` 42 isn't a `Foo<?>`.

Comment: Oops thank you @matt, I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the issue becomes clearer if you leave the generic parameter of Foo out of the equation.

Consider

```
final Set<Foo> set1 = new HashSet<>();
Set<Object> set2 = set1;
```

This makes the compile error more obvious. If this was valid, it would be possible to insert an object into set2, thus into set1 violating the type constraint.

```
Set<? extends Foo> set3 = set1;
```

This is perfectly valid because set1 would also accept types derived from Foo.

Comment: why did you transform `Set<Foo<?>>` to `Set<Object>` after type erasure? I guess wildcard will be replaced by `Object` since it is closest bound?

Comment: `Foo<?>` is not `Object`, it is `Foo` "of something". What allows the assignment to `set3` is the covariance.

Comment: Also you answer implies that `set3` is writable, which is not the case. See more about covariance and contravariance here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/7709086

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the answers given already I'll add some formal explanation.

Given by [4.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2) (emp. mine)

> Given a generic type declaration C (n > 0), the direct
>   supertypes of the parameterized type C, where Ti (1 ≤ i ≤
>   n) is a type, are all of the following:
>
> D < U1 θ,...,Uk θ>, where D is a generic type which is a
>   direct supertype of the generic type C and θ is the
>   substitution [F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn].
>
> **C < S1,...,Sn> , where Si contains Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n) (§4.5.1).**
>
> The type Object, if C is a generic interface type with no
>   direct superinterfaces.
>
> The raw type C.

Rule for `contains` are specified at [4.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1):

> A type argument T1 is said to contain another type argument T2,
>   written T2 <= T1, if the set of types denoted by T2 is provably a
>   subset of the set of types denoted by T1 under the reflexive and
>   transitive closure of the following rules (where <: denotes subtyping
>   (§4.10)):
>
> ? extends T <= ? extends S if T <: S
>
> ? extends T <= ?
>
> ? super T <= ? super S if S <: T
>
> ? super T <= ?
>
> ? super T <= ? extends Object
>
> T <= T
>
> T <= ? extends T
>
> T <= ? super T

Since `T <= ? super T <= ? extends Object = ?` so applying 4.10.2 `Foo<T> <: Foo<?>` we have `? extends Foo<T> <= ? extends Foo<?>`. But `Foo<T> <= ? extends Foo<T>` so we have `Foo<T> <= ? extends Foo<?>`.

Applying 4.10.2 we have that `Set<? extends Foo<?>>` is a direct supertype of `Set<Foo<T>>`.

The formal answer to why your first example does not compile may be got by assuming a contradiction. Percisely:

If `Set<Foo<T>> <: Set<Foo<?>>` we have that `Foo<T> <= Foo<?>` which is not possible to prove applying reflexive or transitive relations to rules from 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think simply because the `Set` element Datatype is different while it must be the same except for Generic Datatype.
the first set `Set<Foo<T>>` datatype  is `Foo<T>`,
then second set `Set<Foo<?>>` is `Foo<?>`,
As I can see the element datatype is different `Foo<T> != Foo<?>` and not generic type because it use `Foo`, so then would cause compilation error.
It is same as below invalid different datatype example :

```
Set<List<T>> set3 = new HashSet<>();
Set<List<?>> set4 = set3;   // compilation error due to different element datatype List<T> != List<?>
```

`Set<? extends Foo<?>> set3 = set1;` can because it have `? datatype` which is generic and have purpose can accept any datatype. 
ex :

```
Set<List<T>> set4 = new HashSet<>();
Set<?> set5 = set4;  // would be Ok
```